# SELECT multiple values and order by relevance

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_subjects` (
  `user_subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_subject_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and I want to get the user_ids that has subject_id 1 or 2, for example, ordered by relevance. (edit: i meant by how many results it matches)

I've tryed this but it doesn't count the relevance. It returns relevance 1.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944ab8/2

For that example i wanted to get

```
user_id relevance
1       1
2       2
```

and the subject_id matched if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "relevance"?  What's that column supposed to return?  Are looking for the `COUNT` of `subject_id` rows?

Comment: `subject_id LIKE 2` will return `TRUE` (`1`) if `subject_id` is `2` and `FALSE` (`0`) otherwise.

Comment: yes, the count of `subject_id`

Comment: Ok.  Just so you know, "relevance" was the wrong word there.  If you wanted the count, then just say that.

Comment: i'm sorry, then :) my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure I follow. Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
     , SUM(CASE WHEN subject_id IN(1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)ttl 
  FROM user_subjects 
 GROUP 
    BY user_id;
```

?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you! But is it possible to get the matched subject_ids too?

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct subject_id) as subjectids`

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin Again, not sure what you mean!

Comment: @ebyrob that will return all the subject_ids a user has, but i need only the matched ones

Comment: So 'relevance' was a complete 'red herring'!

Comment: @strawberry Yea, sorry. I meant 'by relevance' since a user wants to get the most matched results first.

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin a bit long but: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(subject_id IN (1,2), subject_id, NULL) ORDER BY subject_id) AS subject_ids`

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following will I think do what you want, although I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "relevance"; this simply counts the number of rows that match both the user and have `subject_id` 1 or 2:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(subject_id) AS relevance
FROM
  `user_subjects`
WHERE
  subject_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY
  user_id
ORDER BY
  relevance DESC
```

(This is mysql-specific, I believe, because of the use of `relevance` in `ORDER BY`.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I ment. I used the wrong term there. Thanks! But is it possible to get the matched subject_ids too?

Comment: +1 Moving subject_id IN check to WHERE clause is good here I think!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll never get a `relevance` of 2, because `(subject_id LIKE 1) + (subject_id LIKE 2)` will return 1 at most.

Maybe you should rethink your query.